# Event for all elements in form

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, events

I am new to VB and Visual Studio and my question is maybe stupid.

I would like to make a click event for each element inside a form to do the same thing (e.g `me.close()`).

Is there a way to include all the elements of the form in a single event call or should I have to make a click event for every element that has the same code inside?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I don't really know where to start. I would like to include every control of my form but I have no idea how to do it. Coding is smart so in my mind I said there must be a way to do it but I had no clue

Comment: If you don't know where to start then let me suggest a search engine. SO is not a tutorial site. You need to do your own research, make an attempt and then post here if and when you encounter an actual issue.

Comment: Hi Alex, you might start with the [Microsoft documentation on VB events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/).  Once you have some code, if you still have problems the guidance in [ask] and [mcve] will help you construct a more focused question.

Answer (score -1):

If your event is too big then you can write a `public/private sub()` and then call it from elsewhere. But if your code is only like a small event e.g. `me.close()` then writing at two or three places doesn't make the program too long, but if you have controls in hundreds then you can write an event like

E.g. for each control in panel/canvas etc (specify collection) and call

```
Me.close
```

Comment: `Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles`
the point is i don't know what to put after "handles" in order to include every control in the form

Comment: This is far to vague to be an answer to a question that really shouldn't have been answered in the first place because it's too broad.